# Nifi Jolt duplicate an attribute

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I'm new with Jolt and I need to have two field having different name but same value coming from the input JSON.

INPUT:

```
    {
      "date": 15746555589,
      "sensorid": "23r098hd20c8jd02hd0h02300000000000"
    }
```

DESIDERED OUTPUT:

```
    {
      "lastseen": 15746555589,
      "firstseen": 15746555589,
      "sensorid": "23r098hd20c8jd02hd0h02300000000000"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec should work:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "date": "lastseen",
      "@(1,date)": "firstseen",
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: and what do ou think about this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858343/how-to-update-with-putmongo-using-update-query-only-some-parameters)